# Google Maps info window looks screwed up

Tags: php, html, css, google-maps

Check out this site and click the marker on the map. you can see that the info window is screwed up looking. The border is very jagged and not solid. How do I fix that and what is causing it?
http://waterski.allthingswebdesign.com/index.php/site/directions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm using [html5reset](http://html5reset.org) and if you take a look in the reset.css file it has the following lines which cause the issue with google maps. They even have a description in there which states that it causes issues with google maps.

```
/* Responsive images and other embedded objects
   Note: keeping IMG here will cause problems if you're using foreground images as sprites, like, say for Google Maps custom placemarkers. 
   There has been a report of problems with standard Google maps as well, but we haven't been able to duplicate or diagnose the issue. */
img,
object,
embed {max-width: 100%;}
```

Comment: Old thread so i can't remember that well, but i think you just comment out the max-width: 100%.

Comment: Well in my case I needed `img` to keep `max-width` for the rest of my site, but I just made a selector for the maps img's and set `img: { max-width: inherit; }`. Thanks

Comment: @jakobud...you da man. #map img {max-width: inherit;} ("map" is the id of your div your map is contained in).

Answer (score 4):

This is little bit late answer but i got it fixed with this:

```
#map img {
   max-width: none;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is hiding inside your CSS which overwrites Google's one. You have several options to fix it:

- put map inside iframe without any CSS
- make your CSS rules more specific (for example: do not use rules for simple div, h1 and other tags
- make your custom styling for bubble

The easiest way is to the first one of course.

**Update:** [Iframe](http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp) is a frame that resides inline of a page. So you need to create another .html file with Google map only and without your CSS files included. Then your iframe will look like this:

```
<iframe src="map.html" width="100%" height="300"><p>Please upgrade your browser for Iframe support</p></iframe>
```

Comment: Can you post code on how to put the map into an iframe? I've never worked with iframe's and i tried just changing `<div id="map_canvas></div>` to `<iframe id="map_canvas></iframe>` and that doesn't work.

Comment: I tried the iframe but it was too complicated with codeigniter so I just decided to dig into which line was causing the issue in my reset file. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

try removing your css reset code and check whether this fixes it

Comment: It is the reset that causes the issue. I'm not sure what piece exactly yet though.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem in that when my `InfoWindow` appeared it, appeared distorted:
[image: Google Maps distorted InfoWindow]

**The Fix:**
I commented out google-button.css from the page.

```
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="google-buttons.css" type="text/css"  media="screen" />-->
```

Google's own button CSS interfered with their maps CSS.